# How to replace and update all rows of table where varchar date yyyy-dd-mm to dd-mm-yyyy in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a **varchar column** with date format as follows **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0**

**transactions_table**

```
+-----------------------+
| transaction_date      |
+-----------------------+
| 2020-04-29 19:09:06.0 |
| 2020-05-13 19:09:06.0 |
```

---

How can I convert above records in **dd-mm-yyyy** and update the same record as follows

```
+-----------------------+
| transaction_date      |
+-----------------------+
| 29-04-2020           |
| 13-05-2020           |
```

SQL code:

```
 update transactions_table
    set transaction_date ='manipulated data'
    where transaction_date  like '2020%';
```

How can I convert that string and save the same ?

Comment: Avoid storing dates or timestamps as `VARCHAR`, You're asking for trouble.

Comment: yes but for now i am in big trouble need to convert it as soon as possible.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(DATE('2020-04-29 19:09:06.0'),'%d-%m-%Y') `

Comment: Converting is as easy as using  DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date, '%d-%m-%Y') BUT (and it is a big but) while having a datetime is bad enough, having it in  d-m-Y is much worse. At least your current format is sortable and would utilize the index for most date\datetime searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
select date_format(transaction_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
from transactions_table
where transaction_date  like '2020%'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4cZ5mf9FV4ULNSmiRR3gSJ/0).

If you want to update the column:

```
update transactions_table
set transaction_date = date_format(transaction_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
where transaction_date  like '2020%';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4cZ5mf9FV4ULNSmiRR3gSJ/1).

Results:

```
| transaction_date |
| ---------------- |
| 29-04-2020       |
| 13-05-2020       |
```

There is no need to convert the values of the column `transaction_date` to `date`, because this is done implicitly by MySql as the column has the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.0` which is a valid date format.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update using a couple of built in functions

```
UPDATE transactions_table 
    SET transactions_date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE(transaction_date),'%d-%m-%Y');
```